# The member 'IdLogement' is not supported in the 'Where' Azure Mobile Services query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, azure-mobile-services

I use Azure Mobile Service and I try to execute this query :

```
var interventions = await _interventionRemoteTable.Where(inter => inter.Logement.IdLogement == idLogement).ToListAsync();
```

An error occurs each time :
The member 'IdLogement' is not supported in the 'Where' Azure Mobile Services query

If I make this request in two steps (by getting all "Interventions" first and then filtering local), it works.

```
var interventions = await _interventionRemoteTable.ToListAsync();

var result = interventions.Where(inter => inter.Logement.IdLogement == idLogement);
```

Of course, this is not what I want. I want the filtering is done on the server in order to not get thousands of data.

Is there a method for filtering on a navigation property?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Services has a simplified model for querying, which means that you can't directly specify LINQ queries that are based off multiple tables.

I can think of two options to work around this:

1. Write a custom API where you pass in the parameter to filter on, IdLogement in this example.
2. Add a parameter to your GET table controller method to take IdLogement as a parameter, and have the server add an additional .Where clause to do the filtering.